# Can background image and border gradient co-exist?

Tags: html, css

I have a div which I'd like to enrich with a bottom border. The classic one works perfectly, however the gradient one doesn't work at all:

```
div.bg
{
    background-image: url('http://...');
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    border-bottom-width:10px;
    border-bottom-image:linear-gradient(to left, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);
}
```

Comment: Gradients for borders work only in WebKit as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

`border-image` and `background-image` should not affect each other.

Note that not all browsers support `background-size` (See http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts), and even fewer support `border-image` (See http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image).

Answer (score 1):

you can set in background: **image + linear-gradient**
example for an empty `div`:

```
div {
background:
  linear-gradient(90deg, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%) no-repeat bottom,
  url(http://lorempixel.com/640/480/) no-repeat;
padding-bottom:10px;
background-size: 100% 10px, contain;
height: 480px;
width: 640px;
}
```

else,

1. use `:after` `display:block` + gradient.
2. or even as bg in img tag itself to wich you give `border-image` or `padding-bottom`

Comment: i would go for **else 2**, without context it might not be possible